# Change the package name in the Google Play Console

Tags: package, google-play-console

**I have changed the name of my two apps and I would like to change the name of the package in the Google Play Console (I have already changed it in the programming app that I use) since, in production, when putting the App Bundle it tells me that it has to have the same package name.**

I have tried to contact Google and they have told me to do it for this site.

Answer (score 0):

The package name is the identifier of the app, so changing package name effectively means creating a new app in the Play Console. That is the only way to "change" the package name. If you have users, that also means you'd need to ask them to install the new app. As to migrating the user data, there are some ways to do it by having the old app and the new app communicate with each other.